# calculate date and time difference between 2 dates (& time) using robot framework

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Need to calculate date and time difference between 2 dates (& time). one will be input in the format of 'm/d/yy h:m:s' and other is current date and time. I see methods like "Subtract Date From Date" & "Subtract Time From Date" in robot framework documentation. But both are not working as I need to calculate both date and time difference and result should be in minutes. I have written below script, which is not working. Giving error.
Any help/suggestion to get it right would be appreciated.

```
*** Test Cases ***
GetDateAndTimeDifference
    ${date} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%m/%d/%y
    Log To Console    date : ${date}
    ${time} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%I:%M:%S %p
    Log To Console    time : ${time}
    ${datetime} =    Catenate    ${date}    ${time}
    Log To Console    datetime : ${datetime}
    ${diff} =    Subtract Date From Date    ${datetime}    11/10/19 11:11:11 PM
    Log To Console    diff : ${diff}
    ${minutes} =    Convert Time To Seconds    ${diff}
    Log To Console    minutes : ${minutes}
```

Below is the error :

```
ValueError: time data '1225-23-10 36:36:00.000000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Comment: The year in the date is 1225. Is that really a date you're trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you provide an explicit format, the date must be in ISO 8601 format, according to the official documentation:

> If a date is given as a string, it is always considered to be a timestamp. If no custom formatting is given using date_format argument, the timestamp is expected to be in ISO 8601 like format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.mil

You're not using that format and you're not using custom formatting. The code expects something in the form of `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` but you're giving it `12/26/23 12:41:35 PM` (ie: you have a month in the year field, and a two-digit year in the month field.

The simple solution is to specify a valid format when computing the date, and when hard-coding the other date.

```
${date} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%Y-%m-%d
...
${diff} =    Subtract Date From Date    ${datetime}  2019-11-10 11:11:11 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting both the dates and times to epoch time and find the difference (and divide it by 60 of course cuz epoch time is in seconds). I'm sure there's a module for converting a date and time to epoch time.

Comment: I will try this approach. For now, I used Javascript to calculate the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Test Cases ***
GetDateAndTimeDifference
    ${date} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%m/%d/%y
    Log To Console    date : ${date}
    ${time} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%I:%M:%S %p
    Log To Console    time : ${time}
    ${datetime} =    Catenate    ${date}    " "    ${time}   # Corrected line
    Log To Console    datetime : ${datetime}
    ${diff} =    Subtract Date From Date    ${datetime}    11/10/19 11:11:11 PM
    Log To Console    diff : ${diff}
    ${minutes} =    Convert Time To Seconds    ${diff}
    Log To Console    minutes : ${minutes}
```

Comment: nope, same error. Default separator in Catenate is SPACE only. (I guess)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I wrote below block to get the difference in minutes...

```
GetTimeDifference
    [Arguments]    ${processStartTime}
    ${currentDate} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%m/%d/%y    time_zone=UTC
    Log To Console    date : ${currentDate}
    ${currentTime} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%I:%M:%S %p    time_zone=UTC
    Log To Console    time : ${currentTime}
    ${currentDateTime} =    Catenate    ${currentDate}    ${currentTime}
    Log To Console    datetime : ${currentDateTime}
    ${difference}=    Execute Javascript    
    ...    var utcDate = new Date('${currentDate} UTC');
    ...    var inputDate = new Date('${processStartTime} UTC');
    ...    var difference = Math.abs(utcDate - inputDate)/60000;
    ...    return Math.floor(difference);
    Log To Console    diff : ${difference}
    [Return]    ${difference}
```